# Как разместить блоки с товарами по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

нужно расположить блоки с товарами по горизонтали и чтобы расстояние между блоками было 105px.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-item {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.product-item img {
  padding: 0 44px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-list {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.product-list h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #545454;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.price {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #545454;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background-image: url('/img/button.png');
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.product-item:hover .button {
  background-image: url('/img/Button-hover.png');
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Landing<br>page</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product1.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 1.500 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Мини<br>магазин</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product2.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 4.000 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Большой<br>сайт</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product3.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 8.000 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как должно выглядеть:[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Comment: В (.product-item) вписать (display: inline;) а в (.product-list) вписать ( display: inline-block;  width: calc(33% - 24px); )

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Я не совсем правильно подсказал. И у меня есть решение с соблюдением условия "чтобы расстояние между блоками было 105px." Или уже сам разобрался?

Comment: Спасибо, я смог разобраться сам, но если бы Вы мне не подсказали, то скорее всего я бы не смог сам разобраться!

Comment: Вы бы в сторону `flex` посмотрели... Там это делается двумя свойствами.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-item {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    display: flex; /*<---*/
    justify-content: space-evenly; /*<---*/
}

.product-item img {
  padding: 0 44px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-list {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.product-list h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #545454;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.price {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #545454;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background-image: url('/img/button.png');
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.product-item:hover .button {
  background-image: url('/img/Button-hover.png');
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Landing<br>page</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product1.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 1.500 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Мини<br>магазин</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product2.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 4.000 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Большой<br>сайт</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product3.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 8.000 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
</div>
```